# Update LWC component each time when tab with it opened

Tags: lightning-web-components, tab

I have custom LWC component with forecast's table on Opportunity record page in tabs like on picture :
[image]

I want it to be updated each time I open the tab with it. I know how to update the component, but how can I do it each time I open the tab? ConnectedCallback, renderedCallback and wire works only when I open this tab for the first time.
Thanks!

Comment: @glls what event? How can I relate it to opening a tab?

Comment: @glls I mean tabs like Details. I have my own custom tab called "Forecast and income" and i want it to be updated each time i am opening it. There is custom lwc component inside it

Comment: ok, you might want to specify that in your post - 'when opening the detail tab on the record" for clarity.

Comment: can you create a setter for recordId and when it sets new recordId you can catch it and load your record specific data?